KeyError when filtering time series on basis of datetimeindex in pandas
I am trying to filter a time series on the basis of a datetimeindex in pandas, but get a KeyError. The example below for instance yields the error KeyError: '2021'. What causes this?
import pandas as pd

data = {'date':['2021-11-1', '2021-12-1', '2022-01-1', '2022-02-1'],
       'value':['hello', 'bonjour', 'merhaba', 'goeiendag']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

print(df['2021'])
#print(df['2021-01'])
#print(df['2021-01-01'])


Since you want to use the index: print(df.loc['2021'])

df['2021'] would expect '2021' to be a column name.

Thank you @mozway that works. I based my code on this video (3:33 mark for instance) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0s4slGHwzE&list=PLeo1K3hjS3uvMADnFjV1yg6E5nVU4kOob&index=2 Maybe the functionality used there doesn't work anymore?

Old pandas version indeed worked this way. I'd recommend reading the official pandas doc rather than random youtube videos (especially 7 years old) ;)
